# Как добавлять компоненты vue динамически?

Tags: javascript, frontend, vue.js

На сайте есть основной js, и js для конкретной страницы, который уже потом берётся с сервера. **В основном js я создаю экземпляр vue, можно ли после создания, как то потом, когда получу js для страницы, зарегистрировать в нём новые компоненты? Или нужно новый экземпляр vue создавать?** Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то когда загружается второй скрипт, то у него должен быть доступен инстанс Vue, который инициализирован в первом скрипте. Ты можешь сделать его глобальным, чтобы он был доступен во втором скрипте, а потом вызывать

`Vue.component('my-component-name', MyComponent)`

Потом все новые зарегистрированные компоненты будут доступны во втором скрипте.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.